# Fancybox v2 on hover and open new page on click

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a list of products on my page with thumbnail images. I want to use Fancybox 2 to open bigger image in a popup. The problem is that Fancybox 2 works on click only. 
I could easily trigger the click event on hover but the problem is that I want to open the product's detailed page on click. How could I get this working?

Thanks!

Comment: Any code you might be able to provide?

Comment: Just have included the fancybox, created the anchor tags and right now it is working with click. Just like here: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#instructions

Comment: is `the product's detailed page` opened from another link beside the thumbnail?  ....should `the product's detailed page` open in fancybox too? ... why you don't post your html code? ... why we should be guessing things?